# Sequencing both Scalaz WriterT and Either with for-yield

Tags: scala, scalaz

If I have:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

type Z = List[String]
type F[α] = Future[α]
type WT[α] = WriterT[F, Z, α]

implicit val z: Monoid[Z] = new Monoid[Z] {
  def zero = Nil
  def append (f1: Z, f2: => Z) = f1 ::: f2
}
implicit val f: Monad[F] = scalaz.std.scalaFuture.futureInstance
```

I can write code like this:

```
def fooA (): WT[Int] = WriterT.put[F, Z, Int] (f.point (18))(z.zero)
def fooB (): WT[Int] = WriterT.put[F, Z, Int] (f.point (42))(z.zero)
def fooLog (msg: String): WT[Unit] = WriterT.put[F, Z, Unit] (f.point (()))(msg :: Nil))

def foo (): WT[Int] = for {
  _: Unit <- fooLog ("log #1")
  a: Int  <- fooA
  _: Unit <- fooLog ("log #2")
  b: Int  <- fooB
  _: Unit <- fooLog ("log #3")
} yield a + b
```

Suppose I define:

```
type WTT[α] = WriterT[Future, Z, Throwable \/ α]

def flakeyInt (i: Int): Throwable \/ Int = new java.util.Random().nextBoolean match {
  case false => i.right
  case true => new Exception (":-(").left
}
```

I can then write this:

```
def barA (): WTT[Int] = WriterT.put[F, Z, Throwable \/ Int] (f.point (flakeyInt (18)))(z.zero)
def barB (): WTT[Int] = WriterT.put[F, Z, Throwable \/ Int] (f.point (flakeyInt (42)))(z.zero)
def barLog (msg: String): WTT[Unit] = WriterT.put[F, Z, Throwable \/ Unit] (f.point (().right))(msg :: Nil))

def bar (): WTT[Int] = for {
  _: Throwable \/ Unit <- barLog ("log #1")
  x: Throwable \/ Int  <- barA
  _: Throwable \/ Unit <- barLog ("log #2")
  y: Throwable \/ Int  <- barB
  _: Throwable \/ Unit <- barLog ("log #3")
} yield {
  for {
    a <- x
    b <- y
  } yield a + b
}
```

Is there a way to make the `<-` in the for-yield return type `α`, not `\/[Throwable, α]` so I don't have to manually flatten the Throwables at the end?  Ideally I would like to make the `bar` function look like the `foo` function so that I can hide flattening the errors from the logic.

**Follow up question:**

[Customising composition of Future, Either and Writer in Scalaz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674741/stacking-future-either-and-writer-in-scalaz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should wrap your Future monad in the EitherT, sightly modifying your code.
It would look like that:

```
type EFT[α] = EitherT[F, Throwable, α]
type WEFT[α] = WriterT[EFT, Z, α]

def bazA(): WEFT[Int] = WriterT.put[EFT, Z, Int](EitherT.right[F, Throwable, Int](f.point(18)))(z.zero)

def bar(): WEFT[Int] = for {
  a <- bazA
  b <- bazA
} yield a + b
```

You can also define lift functions (which lifts the value from one monad to your transformer) to avoid boilerplate.

```
def liftW[A](fa: Future[A]): WLET[A] = {
    WriterT.put[MLT, Z, A](EitherT.right[Future, Throwable, A](fa))(z.zero)
 }

  def bbar(): WLET[Int] = for {
    a ← liftW(6.point[F])
    b ← liftW(6.point[F])
  } yield a + b
```

I am sure that lift functions are present in scalaZ, but I am always struggling to find them, and it appears that sometimes these are easier to write yourself.

Comment: I've noticed a subtle difference between my original intention for this code and this solutions behaviour.  If a `-\/` is returned anywhere, the logging context will be lost.

Comment: If logging data was added before both `a <- bazA` and `b <- bazA` like in the question and then the function `bazB` was changed to return a Left Exception, then when the `WriterT` `run` method is called on the value returned by  `bar` we get `Future[EitherT[Z, α]]` which leaves us with no way to get the logs that happened before the failure occurs.

Comment: I am not sure, that I understood you correctly, but if you want to add a log, you can still do it in the for comprehension:  `... for {
    a ← liftW(6.point[F]) :++> List("adding future of six")
    ...
  } yield a + b` or with `:++>>` in WriterT

Comment: And then, if you want to access your log, you do `bbar.written`. If you want to unwrap it, you do `bbar.run` and it returns `-\/` if throwable was returned anywhere. So you are able to view the log without running WriterT and hence without knowing was there throwable anywhere or not