# scalaz - function composition - WriterT

Tags: scala, scalaz, monad-transformers, writer-monad

Let's define a `Kleisli` on `\/`:

```
abstract class MyError
case class NumericalError(msg: String) extends MyError

// Either is a Monad with two type parameters: M[A,B] which represent left and right respectively
// Let's create an ad-hoc type
type EEither[+T] = \/[MyError, T]
```

and one ad-hoc function for testing purposes:

```
def safeSqrtEither(t: Double): EEither[Double] =
  safeSqrtOpt(t) match {
    case Some(r) => r.right
    case None => NumericalError("Sqrt on double is not define if _ < 0").left
  }
val kSafeSqrtEither = Kleisli.kleisli( (x: Double) => safeSqrtEither(x) )
```

Function composition works smoothly:

```
val pipeEither = kSafeSqrtEither >>> kSafeSqrtEither
val r5b = pipeEither2 run 16.0
//which gives r5b: EEither[Double] = \/-(2.0)
```

I'd like to add logging:

```
type LoggedROCFun[I,O] = I => WriterT[EEither,scalaz.NonEmptyList[String],O]
val sqrtWithLog: LoggedROCFun[Double, Double] =
  (t: Double) =>
    WriterT.put(kSafeSqrtEither(t))(s"squared $t".wrapNel)
```

which seems having the desired behaviour:

```
val resA = sqrtWithLog(16.0)
// resA: scalaz.WriterT[EEither,scalaz.NonEmptyList[String],Double] = WriterT(\/-((NonEmpty[squared 16.0],4.0)))
```

Sleek. However, I am struggling to put together an operator which:

- combines the values in the `WriterT` applying `>>>`
- chains (appends) each log, keeping track of each step made

Desired output:

```
val combinedFunction = sqrtWithLog >>> sqrtWithLog
val r = combinedFunction run 16.0
// r: WriterT(\/-((NonEmpty[squared 16.0, squared 4.0],2.0)))
```

My best shot:

```
def myCompositionOp[I,A,B](f1: LoggedROCFun[I,A])(f2: LoggedROCFun[A,B]): LoggedROCFun[I,B] =
  (x: I) => {
    val e = f1.apply(x)
    val v1: EEither[A] = e.value
    v1 match {
        case Right(v)  => f2(v)
        case Left(err) =>
          val lastLog = e.written
          val v2 = err.left[B]
          WriterT.put(v2)(lastLog)

      }
  }
```

In the above I first apply `f1` to `x`, and then I pass along the result to `f2`. Otherwise, I short-circuit to `Left`.
This is wrong, because in the case `Right` I am dropping the previous logging history.

**One last Q**

```
val safeDivWithLog: Kleisli[W, (Double,Double), Double] =
  Kleisli.kleisli[W, (Double, Double), Double]( (t: (Double, Double)) => {
    val (n,d) = t
    WriterT.put(safeDivEither(t))(s"divided $n by $d".wrapNel)
  }
  )
val combinedFunction2 = safeDivWithLog >>> sqrtWithLog
val rAgain = combinedFunction2 run (-10.0,2.0)
// rAgain: W[Double] = WriterT(-\/(NumericalError(Sqrt on double is not define if _ < 0)))
```

Not sure why the logs are not carried through after a pipeline switches to `Left`. Is it because:

- type MyMonad e w a = ErrorT e (Writer w) a is isomorphic to (Either e a, w)
- type MyMonad e w a = WriterT w (Either e) a is isomorphic to Either r (a, w)

[therefore I have flipped the order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31674741/customising-composition-of-future-either-and-writer-in-scalaz?rq=1)?

Sources: [here](https://gist.github.com/tjweir/3349857), [scalaz](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz-day15), [here](http://virtuslab.com/blog/arrows-monads-and-kleisli-part-i/), and [real world haskell on transformers](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monad-transformers.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close—the issue is just that you've buried your `Kleisli`, while you want it on the outside. Your `LoggedROCFun` is just an ordinary function, and the `Compose` instance for ordinary functions demands that the output of the first function match the type of the input of the second. If you make `sqrtWithLog` a kleisli arrow it'll work just fine:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

abstract class MyError
case class NumericalError(msg: String) extends MyError

type EEither[T] = \/[MyError, T]

def safeSqrtEither(t: Double): EEither[Double] =
  if (t >= 0) math.sqrt(t).right else NumericalError(
    "Sqrt on double is not define if _ < 0"
  ).left

type W[A] = WriterT[EEither, NonEmptyList[String], A]

val sqrtWithLog: Kleisli[W, Double, Double] =
  Kleisli.kleisli[W, Double, Double](t =>
    WriterT.put(safeSqrtEither(t))(s"squared $t".wrapNel)
  )

val combinedFunction = sqrtWithLog >>> sqrtWithLog
val r = combinedFunction run 16.0
```

Note that I've modified your code slightly for the sake of making it a complete working example.

---

In response to your comment: if you want the writer to accumulate across failures, you'll need to flip the order of `Either` and `Writer` in the transformer:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

abstract class MyError
case class NumericalError(msg: String) extends MyError

type EEither[T] = \/[MyError, T]

def safeSqrtEither(t: Double): EEither[Double] =
  if (t >= 0) math.sqrt(t).right else NumericalError(
    "Sqrt on double is not define if _ < 0"
  ).left

type W[A] = Writer[List[String], A]
type E[A] = EitherT[W, MyError, A]

val sqrtWithLog: Kleisli[E, Double, Double] =
  Kleisli.kleisli[E, Double, Double](t =>
    EitherT[W, MyError, Double](safeSqrtEither(t).set(List(s"squared $t")))
  )

val constNegative1: Kleisli[E, Double, Double] =
  Kleisli.kleisli[E, Double, Double](_ => -1.0.point[E])

val combinedFunction = sqrtWithLog >>> constNegative1 >>> sqrtWithLog
```

And then:

```
scala> combinedFunction.run(16.0).run.written
res9: scalaz.Id.Id[List[String]] = List(squared 16.0, squared -1.0)
```

Note that this won't work with `NonEmptyList` in the writer, since you need to be able to return an empty log in the case of e.g. `constNegative1.run(0.0).run.written`. I've used a `List`, but in real code you'd want a type with less expensive appends.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seems that the `WriterT` drops the logs when a `Left` is hit (pls, see above). Tnx